# Oracle push notification using asp.net web forms using c# and oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, signalr, real-time

I wanted to implement a real time push notification web application using asp.net c# and Oracle as backend. There are plenty of tutorials for ms sqlserver using sqldependency, of course oracledependency is also available with oracle. Even I couldn't find any tutorials on signalR with oracle.

Are there any better ways or methods to implement push notification using asp.net web forms using c# and Oracle for getting real time data?

Comment: How real time does it need to be? Could you get away with polling the  database every so often, then sending the notifications out with SignalR? Or what about triggering the notifications from application code when it happens?

Comment: real time on the go when there are any changes on the db table and would reflect back as a notification for the user.

Comment: That doesn't really address either of my questions. Would it be acceptable to poll the database every 1 second? Every 5 seconds? Or, if you can restructure the application so that any changes to the table result in calling out to your hub.

Comment: Yes that would do...but wouldn't​ it be affecting the memory usage and hog the DB?

Comment: Only one way to find out.